# Configure nginx conf for docker network

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I have a docker-compose with some containers in the same network, mainly 3: nginx as a proxy, a webserver with Laravel, and a web with reactjs.

I'm trying to configure the default.conf for nginx, but I can't do this correctly:

I' trying:

- Access localhost:80/api -> use my webserver container
- Access localhost:80/{all of the rest} -> use my web container

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass: http://web:3000;
    }

    location /api {
        fastcgi_pass webserver:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to put `location /api` before `location /`?

Comment: You need to share your docker compose so we can help you. At least simplest one should be, eg https://github.com/kgnblg/react-laravel-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yaml, the using proxy pass to map / to react port 80 and /api to port 8080 on docker.

Comment: Thx guys, I solver, just I put the api before / and it's working!